# undefined method `password' for #<User:1123123123>

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, model, controller

I'm following this video tutorial and learning how to create authentication from scratch:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O5RDisWr_7Q

---

Here is my migration file for User:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_hash
      t.string :password_salt

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And my controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:users])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
end
```

And finally my Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password_hash, :password_salt

  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates :password, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end
end
```

---

Now, I think I know why this error is firing; obviously the `@user.save` call is trying to save the value in `password` to the password field in the User table, but that field doesn't exist in the database. In the video he mentions that to fix this bug I should just add: `attr_accessible :password` to my model and it should work, but I get the following error:

> NoMethodError in UsersController#create
>
> undefined method `password' for #
>
> app/controllers/users_controller.rb:8:in `create'

Any suggestions? I just would like to take advantage of the validations that come with using a strongly typed model instead of loose html fields.

Comment: I'm such a dolt - After carefully writing out my question I noticed that I need to use `attr_accessor :password`. D'oh! I'm going to read about the difference between accessor and accessible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `attr_accessible :password_hash, :password_salt`, but I think it should be `attr_accessible :password` together with `attr_accessor :password` since you need a virtual attribute `password` on which you work in your `encrypt_password` method. So:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password
  attr_accessor :password
end
```

`attr_accessor` creates the virtual attribute which is not available as a database field (therefore virtual).

`attr_accessible` is a security mechanism to white-list attributes which are allowed to be set through mass-assignment like you do with `User.new(params[:users])`

Comment: @pduersteler, can you please tell my what can i do in rails 4.0, for the same kind of problem? attr_accessible is not working :(

Comment: @Emu that's also rails4 compatible. If it is not working, you may have another problem there.

Comment: @Emu then you need to open up a new question and provide enough code so we can help.